# How to iterate through an array then replace data of a matching id

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

Okay so what i am trying to do is Iterate through Json decoded array then search for an ID(key) then post that data into a form for editing then encode it then save it it seems like such an easy task however i am not using a data base or java or java script i have to do this using only Json, PHP and HTML my main code(Controller) file is as follows

```
<?php

$file_name = 'engagements.json'; // Serialized speaking engagments

/**
* Controller for Speaking Engagements
*/

if (!isset($_REQUEST['act']) || !$action = $_REQUEST['act']){
  $action = 'list';
} //End If

switch ($action) {
  case 'list': // List
    $json_data = file_get_contents($file_name);
    if (!$engagements = json_decode($json_data, true)) { // Convert serialized data to               array
      $engagements = array();
    } //End If
    include 'engagements_list.phtml';
    break;

  case 'view': // View
    $json_data = file_get_contents($file_name);
    $temp_array = json_decode($json_data);

    foreach($temp_array as $key=>$id){
      if($id->ID == 2){
        echo "got it \n";
        echo "ID: $id->ID \n";
        echo "Title: $id->Title \n";
        echo "Description: $id->Description \n";
      }// End If
    }
    break;

  case 'add': // Add
    $temp_array = array();
    $file = file_get_contents($file_name);
    $json_data = json_decode($file);
    $high_value = count($json_data);
    $high_value++;
    $temp_array['ID'] = $high_value;
    $temp_array['Title'] = $_POST['Title'];
    $temp_array['Description'] = $_POST['Description'];
    $json_data[] = $temp_array;
    file_put_contents($file_name, json_encode($json_data));

    include 'engagements_add.phtml';
    break;

  case 'edit': // Edit

    $file = file_get_contents($file_name);
    $json_data = json_decode($file, true);

    // what comes next here

    include 'engagements_edit.phtml';
    break;

  case 'delete': // Delete
    break;

  default:
    throw(new Exception('Invalid action given'));
    break;
}//End Switch

exit;

<!-- Edit View -->
<form action="engagements.php?act=edit?ID=<?php $_GET['ID']?>" method="get">
  <table>
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="ID"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" style="width:500px;" name="Title"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><textarea cols="40" rows="2" style="width: 500px; height:250px;" name="Description"></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

please help me i have searched everywhere for an answer but can find any resources that explain how to do this properly

Comment: So what's actually not working? What is it doing or not doing? What error messages do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Tiny one point.

```
<form action="engagements.php?act=edit?ID=<?php $_GET['ID']?>" method="get">
```

I'm assuming you meant to type like this:

```
<form action="engagements.php?act=edit&ID=<?php echo $_GET['ID']?>" method="get">
```

The `$_GET` statement was missing an `echo`, too.

**UPDATE:**

I notice php close tag `?>` missing until EDIT VIEW. And 'view' part in switch, why you echo ID property? It might be following:

```
echo "ID: $id['ID'] \n";
```

Comment: There's no echo when trying to add the ID to the action, either

Comment: I notice your code missing php close tag ?>. Is there no error output? If no error, write which part in switch is the problem. list, view, add, any other